# Schedule change of field

Tags: 7, rules, actions

Rules does not allow data selection of fields without first knowing the node type actually has said field.

Rules only allows you to schedule components.

Rules action components can't have conditions to fulfill the first requirement.

How do I schedule a "Set a data value" action on a field?

I considered passing the field as a parameter to the component but it will only let me send "Entity" types and a binary value is not an "Entity" apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules action components do not have conditions, but you can also add a component that is a rule itself, not an action set, and then schedule that.  Then you can just add the condition *node: has type* and then do *set a data value* however you like.